# Propagate value of hidden field in php

Tags: php, post, hidden-field

this is my code

```
<?php
    if (!strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'){ 
        $hdnNumber = rand(10, 500);}
    else
        if(isset($_POST["hiddenNumber"]))
            $hdnNumber = $_POST["hiddenNumber"];
    echo $hdnNumber ; 
    ?>        
<form action="" method="post">
        Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenNumber" value="<?= $hdnNumber ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

I want to propagate the value of $hdnNumber on all form posts, and its value should be the random value generated on page load.

When I am submitting the form, it again creates a new random number, but I want to maintain the first value only.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to store $hdnNumber in a Session

Comment: You could make use of sessions then. Assign `$_SESSION['hidden_number']=$hdnNumber;` or *vice-versa*, then just echo it after and will work for other pages also. `session_start();` is to be included also.

Comment: I didn't see your comment @MarioJohnathan I was busy typing mine up. lol

Comment: so you mean this thing is not possible with hidden field?

Comment: Yes it is possible @HariChaudhary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only set the value when the value is blank/unset, e.g.

```
$hdnNumber = isset($_POST['hiddenNumber']) ? $_POST['hiddenNumber'] : rand(10,500);
```

Answer (score 1):

To compliment [**Marc B's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857345/) and the usage of a [**ternary operator**](http://php.net/ternary), you can use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to pass on that (*hidden*) value to another page and any subsequent page when using sessions.

**Sidenote**: Although you can pass that (*hidden*) number in a second page using
`$hdnNumber = $_POST['hiddenNumber'];` you are limited to just that.

Should you want to use it for DB-related work, you could assign it to a session variable that can subsequently be used anywhere else thereafter.

This could prove to be useful when implemented into DB work.

**HTML form**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Borrowed from Marc B's answer
$hdnNumber = isset($_POST['hiddenNumber']) ? $_POST['hiddenNumber'] : rand(10,500); 
$_SESSION['hiddenNumber']=$hdnNumber;

// my own testing method
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_SESSION['hiddenNumber'];
}
?>        
<form action="" method="post">
Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenNumber" value="<?= $hdnNumber ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<a href="hidden_session.php">Verify the number</a>
```

---

**hidden_session.php**

(will echo the number from the initial HTML form)

```
<?php
session_start();
$test=$_SESSION['hiddenNumber'];
echo $test;
?>
<a href="session_check2.php">Go here</a>
```

---

**session_check2.php**

(will echo the same number, initially coming from HTML form, that was passed on to the second page)

```
<?php
session_start();
$test=$_SESSION['hiddenNumber'];
echo $test;
```

Using `echo $_SESSION['hiddenNumber'];` will also work.